# Ruby select method: check number of items that are selected

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, methods

So, Ruby has a select method that can pick the elements from an array based on conditions passed in from a block.

For example

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
arr.select {|x| x.even? } => [2, 4]
```

My problem deals with a large array, and I only want a certain number of items selected. For example, out of the array, I only want the first 5 numbers that matches the condition.

```
arr.select{|x| x.even?}[0...5]
```

This is what I have so far. This is extremely slow because Ruby runs the select function on the entire array before picking the first five element.

I want to see if there is a way to stop the select function when the first five elements are selected.

For example, if I can do this

```
res = arr.select do |x|
  x.even? 
  break if self.length > 5
end
```

In this case, self is a reference to the res array. I don't think that reference will work, but I hope it gets my point across.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In this case, self is a reference to the res array.

The keyword `self` in Ruby gives you access to the current object – the object that is receiving the current message.

I think it is a job for [`Enumerator::Lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html):

```
>> (1..100000).lazy.select { |x| x.even? }.first(5)
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`lazy` is tailor-made for this, but you could also write

```
1.step.each_with_object([]) do |x, arr|
   arr << x if x.even?
   break arr if arr.size == 5
end
  #=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Also, [Enumerator#lazy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) saw the light of day in Ruby v2.0, [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) in v1.9, [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`), which also could be used, much earlier, so your choice of method may depend on the earliest version of Ruby you wish to support. One more thing: if efficiency is important you may want to benchmark, as `lazy` has a reputation for being relatively slow.